# doctrine:schema:update not creating OneToOne relations

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, one-to-one

When I run the following command: `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --dump-sql`

It returns this message: `Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata`.

I have two Entities, User and UserProfile.

User.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users", options={"charset":"utf8mb4", "collate":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserProfile", inversedBy="user_id")
     */
    private $id;
...
```

UserProfile.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users_profiles", options={"charset":"utf8mb4", "collate":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserProfileRepository")
 */
class UserProfile
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="id")
     */
    private $userId;
...
```

I've already tried clearing the cache.

**UPDATE #1**

User.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserProfile", mappedBy="userId")
 */
private $id;
```

UserProfile.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="id")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $userId;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options here, if you want a bi-direction association, meaning you want to be able to access the other entity from either of them then you will want to use another property( NOT the `$id`) to accomplish this. Something like:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users", options={"charset":"utf8mb4", "collate":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")         
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserProfile", mappedBy="userId")
     */
    private $profile;

    ...
}
```

Then in UserProfile.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users_profiles", options={"charset":"utf8mb4", "collate":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserProfileRepository")
 */
class UserProfile
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")         
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="profile")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userId", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;

    ...
}
```

This will allow you to do `$userProfile->getUser()` and also `$user->getProfile()`.

If you want to use the userId as your primary key for the UserProfile table, you can it just involves more work to set that up and you have to explicitly set it in your application. Easier just to reference it on another field.

**Unidirectional**

User.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users", options={"charset":"utf8mb4", "collate":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")         
     */
    private $id;

    ...
}
```

UserProfile.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users_profiles", options={"charset":"utf8mb4", "collate":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserProfileRepository")
 */
class UserProfile
{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="profile")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userId", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;

    ...
}
```

This will only allow you to do `$userProfile->getUser()`. Likely not what you are looking for. The other unidirectional solution is from the user object towards the UserProfile, like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users", options={"charset":"utf8mb4", "collate":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")         
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserProfile", mappedBy="id")
     */
    private $profile;

    ...
}
```

Then in UserProfile.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users_profiles", options={"charset":"utf8mb4", "collate":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserProfileRepository")
 */
class UserProfile
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")         
     */
    private $id;

    ...
}
```

This way you can do `$user->getProfile()`.

Comment: While I understand why it is necessary and recommended, it bothers me that I need 2 extra properties and 1 extra field. There's going to be exactly the same rows in both tables, and the user_profile_id is going to be the same as the user_id (unless something goes terribly wrong). Anyway, your answer solved my problem, thank you!

Comment: You can get away with doing it with just the one column, its just a lot of extra work that to me is just easier to add the extra property. But i do feel your frustration. Glad the answer was helpful.

Comment: On that last option, on the `$profile` property, you wrote `mappedBy="userId"` but there is no `userId` anywhere.

Comment: Copy paste fail, it should be just `id` i have updated the answer

Comment: The `$profile` also needs `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="profile_id", referencedColumnName="id")`, right?

Answer (score 0):

inversedBy refers to the property, not the database field.

Change `inversedBy="user_id"` to `inversedBy="userId"`

You should also use JoinColumn, not Column, and referencedColumnName as per the documentation:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-unidirectional

Comment: It still doesn't work it seems. I've updated the code your tips in the OP.